# How to add data to an existing file and also read it with Java

Tags: java

This is a simple program where the user inputs two variable values and chooses an operator. THe program displays the results and then asks the user if they would like to save to a file. The format should be x + y = z. The declared variable which should catch that user input is

```
    resW = "";
```

I am unable to get resW to capture the user input variable values so that it can be then saved to the file. If I enter

```
    resW = "x + y = z";
```

then that is what is saved. Second problem...when it saves it writes over the previous save. I need it to save each entry as a new line. I don't know how to do that.

Finally, I also would like to view the file as well. As far as I can tell all that I need is the FileReader and BufferedReader to do so. It is not working though and simply moves on to the next line of code.

```
if (answer.equals("Y")||answer.equals("y")){
    System.out.println(resW);
    bufferedWriter.write(resW);
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    System.out.println("Results Saved to File.");   
}
System.out.println("Do you want to review the results Y/N");
answer = inS.nextLine();

if (answer.equals("Y")||answer.equals("y")){
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
}
```

Comment: Could whomever dropped the rating for my question also leave a comment explaining why? I am a noob and am trying to improve. How can I improve if you guys knock my question down. It could potentially not get answered. If there is a reason to knock it down then let me know and give me a chance to fix it. My ultimate goal, like everyone else here, is to get a question answered.

Comment: I'm not your down-voter, but I think that you might get better help if you could post a small compilable and runnable program, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that well illustrates your problem for us. That is if ControlAltDel's answer doesn't fix your problem for you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels. I didn't know that. ControlAltDel's answer didn't work and it's probably because no one can run my program. I'll rework it so it fits the MCVE profile. Thanks again.

Comment: ...........oh well........

Answer (score 0):

Just use a PrintWriter, and PrintWriter.println, and be sure to close the file

```
if (answer.equals("Y")||answer.equals("y")) {
    System.out.println(resW);
    printWriter.println(resW);
    printWriter.close();
```